# Convexity of the nullspace of a bounded linear operator

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space and $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$.

> Let $ker(A)=\{x\in E; Ax=0\}$. Is $ker(A)$ always a convex set?

Thank you.

Comment: Linear (real or complex) subspaces are always convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x, y \in \ker(A)$, i.e. $Ax = Ay = 0$. Then, $tx + (1-t)y \in \ker(A)$ because $A(tx+(1-t)y) = tA(x) + (1-t)A(y) = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

For $x,y\in\ker A$ and $t\in[0,1]$, then $A(tx+(1-t)y)=tAx+(1-t)Ay=0$, so $tx+(1-t)y\in\ker A$.